# How to move my files to iCloud drive without using my local disk space?

Tags: icloud, hard-drive, mojave, disk-utility, partition

I have a Mac running Mojave and got into a situation where I don't know how to solve:

My 512Gb SSD disk is divided into 2 partitions (200Gb and 300Gb each):

The first partition is where the OS resides, as well as the Documents, Applications and other OS folders.

The second partition is just a plain disk where I have all of my files stores (Personal, Work, Etc.).

Both disks are getting full, and in the past I used an external disk to keep older files and other bigger stuff (like Virtual Machine big files and so on).

No I've decided to move to the cloud, and I've subscribed a 2TB iCloud drive available. I've configured it properly so that I got the iCloud drive at Finder, and I've also opted for storage optimization where Mojave handles automatically if the local disk is getting full, keeping files only at iCloud.

All set, I started to move stuff to iCloud. Files from the first partition where moved to iCloud drive folder and got synced with no problem. The biggest ones where stored only at iClound and a download icon appeared in case I need to download then.

For the second partition, I've started moving files to the iCloud drive, and here is where the problem resides. They cannot be moved because "There is not enough disk to copy NNNN folder".

I'm now stuck with the following situation:

- Only 15Gb left on partition one
- More than 1Tb available at iCloud
- About 470Gb of files at partition 2 to be moved to iCloud

My questions:

1. How do I properly move the partition 2 files to the iCloud?
2. Is there a way to setup the local disk threshold to trigger storage only on iCloud Drive, not keeping local files and releasing local disk?
3. Is there a way to choose if a folder will be stored locally and at the iCloud or just at the iCloud?

Comment: How about using Symlink (mapping your primary disk's folder to your 2nd partition's one) and move the content to iCloud?